# SUMPRODUCT Formula with Wild Card

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard, sumproduct

With my dummy data this works -

```
=SUMPRODUCT($KO1363:$LN1363*($KO1362:$LN1362<>"Total")*ISFORMULA($KO1363:$LN1363))
```

But in reality, the name of the column could be '2022 - Total' or 'Year Total'. So I need a wildcard.

But this is not working -

```
=SUMPRODUCT($KO1363:$LN1363*($KO1362:$LN1362<>"*Total")*ISFORMULA($KO1363:$LN1363))
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can incorporate a wild card into a SUMPRODUCT function?

Comment: `(Right(range,5)="Total")` ?

Answer (score 2):

`=` does not support wildcards. Use `FIND` to match `Total` in any part of the column header:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($KO1363:$LN1363*ISERROR(FIND("Total",$KO1362:$LN1362))*ISFORMULA($KO1363:$LN1363))
```

If the `Total` is always at the end of the column name, then you can use `RIGHT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($KO1363:$LN1363*(RIGHT($KO1362:$LN1362,5)<>"Total")*ISFORMULA($KO1363:$LN1363))
```